# Use alias-like variable in for loops

Tags: for-loop, vhdl, alias

Is it possible to create an alias variable/signal to improve readability of `for` loops in VHDL processes?

For instance, consider the following module which contains a process with inner `for` loops (code is for example purpose, I haven't test it):

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity MyModule is
  port (
    clk                 : in  std_logic;
    inData              : in  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    outData             : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end MyModule;

architecture functional of MyModule is
  type sample_vector  is array (natural range <>) of std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
  type data_t is record
    samples     : sample_vector(3 downto 0);
    -- other elements...
  end record data_t;
  type data_vector  is array (natural range <>) of data_t;
  signal data  : data_vector(1 downto 0);

begin  -- functional
  process (clk)
  begin  -- process
    if clk'event and clk = '1' then
      -- Set outData(N) to '1' if at least 1 of the last 10 values of inData(N) was '1'
      for d in data'RANGE loop
        for s in data(0).samples'RANGE loop
          data(d).samples(s)(9 downto 1) <= data(d).samples(s)(8 downto 0);
          data(d).samples(s)(0) <= inData(d * 4 + s);
          outData(d * 4 + s) <= '0';
          for b in data(d).samples(s)'RANGE loop
            if data(d).samples(s)(b) = '1' then
              outData(d * 4 + s) <= '1';
            end if;
          end loop;
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end if;
  end process;

end functional;
```

Having to use `data(d).samples(s)` every time I need to reference that signal is cumbersome, so I'd rather use an alias-like variable, something like that instead (inspired from `generate` syntax, `idx` part is just a bonus):

```
      -- Set outData(N) to '1' if at least 1 of the last 10 values of inData(N) was '1'
      for d in data'RANGE loop
        for s in data(0).samples'RANGE loop
          alias sample  : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) is data(d).samples(s);
          constant idx  : integer := d * 4 + s;
        begin
          sample(9 downto 1) <= sample(8 downto 0);
          sample(0) <= inData(idx);
          outData(idx) <= '0';
          for b in sample'RANGE loop
            if sample(b) = '1' then
              outData(idx) <= '1';
            end if;
          end loop;
        end loop;
      end loop;
```

Of course, this does not work. So, is there any way to achieve something like that in VHDL, or do we always have to specify the full signal "path" each time?

I could replace the loop body with a procedure, but having to declare the procedure code in a (far away) different place of the file reduces readability even more. I could also use a `for ... generate` construct, but this will create 1 process for each iteration and prevent me from using common process variables inside the iteration.

Comment: The expression `id * 4 + s`can produce a value outside the index range of `inData`  Provide an error free [mcve] as a basis for compaction allowing a solution to be demonstrated. **For loop statements do not allow declarations other than of the loop parameter**. Note `idx` and `sample` could be variables in the declarative region enclosing the for loops and assigned in the for loop with the parameter `s`.

Comment: @user1155120 I've fixed the example to match your remarks, thanks. If I use process variables to implement that alias concept, I'm worried the synthesis tool might not implement the iteration as parallel paths since each iteration will depend on the variables value and each iteration changes that value. I know the value will only change at the start of each iteration so there is no dependency between iterations, but I'm not sure the synthesis tools are smart enough to find out...

Comment: By unrolling the loops, it becomes clear how synthesis tools can find out the process variables value is not reused between iterations. Vivado produces the same nets at least. @user1155120 thanks for the suggestion. If you want to post an answer with that solution, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated in question comments, this can be achieve using process variables:

```
  process (clk)
    variable sample : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    variable idx    : integer;
  begin  -- process
    if clk'event and clk = '1' then
      -- Set outData(N) to '1' if at least 1 of the last 10 values of inData(N) was '1'
      for d in data'RANGE loop
        for s in data(0).samples'RANGE loop
          -- Helpers
          sample := data(d).samples(s);
          idx := d * 4 + s;

          outData(idx) <= '0';
          for b in sample'RANGE loop
            if sample(b) = '1' then
              outData(idx) <= '1';
            end if;
          end loop;
          sample(9 downto 1) <= sample(8 downto 0);
          sample(0) <= inData(idx);

          -- Do not forget to apply changes
          data(d).samples(s) <= sample;
        end loop;
      end loop;
    end if;
  end process;
```

Of course, using process variables implies changing the operations order to get the same behavior.

Since process variables are read and written in the loops, I was worried the synthesis tools would believe the result of iteration `N` was dependent on the result of iteration `N-1`, and make implements the iterations in series (instead of in parallel). However, after unrolling the loop (which is what synthesis tools do), it gets clear the synthesis tools will see `sample` and `idx` values are not re-used between iterations.